# Hibernate: Map hashmap to table

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap

I have to deal with database, where new tables are added constantly to represent some users data, the solution I came with is to represent each table with hashmap where keys are columns' names, so is it doable in hibernate to map such a hashmap to a table where each value must be inserted in a column having its key as name ? or can the name attribute of @Column be dynamic ?
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Afaik no. That's not what hibernate is made for. This can be done with NoSQL databases such as elasticsearch.

Comment: Approach which you are looking for is more likely with NOSQL database example Mongo-Db, Casandra and ElasticSearch, however if you go with the NOSQL database the api they provide to you for making CRUD operation they will return record in form of Map so you don't need to worried about that.